# How do I merge two columns into one? PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I run a database for a bowling league and each week, we all bowl 2 games. Game 1 score is put into game1_score column, Game 2 score is put into game2_score column and I get an output like this:

Table name: player_scores

```
season_id|nick_name         |g1_score|g2_score|
---------+------------------+--------+--------+
        2|Axel              |     133|     210|
        2|Benjie B          |      91|     163|
        2|Steveball         |     149|     159|
        2|Shadynasty        |     132|     157|
        2|MatT K            |     122|     151|
```

I am looking for a way to find the highest scores, regardless if it's game 1 or game 2. My expected result would be:

```
season_id|nick_name         |high_game|
---------+------------------+--------+
        2|Axel              |     210|
        2|Benjie B          |     163|
        2|Steveball         |     159|
        2|Shadynasty        |     157|
        2|MatT K            |     151|
        2|Steveball         |     149|
        2|Axel              |     133|
        2|Shadynasty        |     132|
        2|MatT K            |     122|
        2|Benjie B          |      91|
```

All I've been able to do so far is get the max from game 1 or game 2, as such:

```
season_id|nick_name         |high_game|
---------+------------------+--------+
        2|Axel              |     210|
        2|Benjie B          |     163|
        2|Steveball         |     159|
        2|Shadynasty        |     157|
        2|MatT K            |     151|
```

Is there a way to do this or should I be inserting all scores (whether it's game 1 or game 2) into the same column moving forward?

I am using PostgreSQL 13.3.

I appreciate any help and insights you can give or even if attempting. Thank you so much!

Comment: You don't seem to want the "high scores".  You seem to want all scores ordered in a descending way.

Comment: If an answer provided resolved your issue, please accept it. This helps future users with similar questions. Do not just leave a successfully question in open status.

Comment: thank you Belayer, didn't see that option but just marked it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

following example works for me

```
with highscores as (
                select season_id, nickname, g1_score as high_game 
                from player_scores ps1
                union 
                select season_id, nickname, g2_score as high_game 
                from player_scores ps2
               )
select * from highscores order by high_game desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to unpivot the data and sort:

```
select ps.nickname, v.score
from player_scores ps cross join lateral
     (values (g1_score), (g2_score) ) v(score)
order by v.score desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off normalizing your data with a result being that games as in a single column with an additional column indicating the particular game. However, you can get what your looking for with the current structure. Instead of selecting (or in addition) use the [greatest](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST) function on g1_score and g2_score.

```
select ps.season_id
     , ps.nick_name
     , ps.g1_score
     , ps.g2_score
     , greatest(ps.g1_score, ps.g2_score) high_game
from player_scores ps 
order by greatest(ps.g1_score, ps.g2_score) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select nick_name, g1_score high_score 
from score_players
where season_id = 2
union
select nick_name, g2_score high_score 
from score_players
where season_id = 2
order by high_score desc
```

ended up working for me, thank you everyone for taking a look!